# Some JavaFX Imports Cannot Be Resolved in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, javafx, compiler-errors

I am creating a small JavaFX library and have run into some issues with the imports. I have been doing my programming on both my PC and my laptop by just hosting the Eclipse Workspace on Dropbox and everything was working fine. I installed e(fx)clipse on both machines and have been making a JavaFX program for a couple months now with no issues.

Now, I recently started a new project on my laptop that was also working fine; however, when I went to my PC, I discovered a bunch of "The import _____ cannot be resolved" errors.

The weird thing is, most of the javafx classes are importing fine, it just seems that some classes in the `javafx.scene.control` package are having issues. In the one class I have so far, I am importing these JavaFX classes:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
```

They all work fine except for three: `javafx.scene.control.ButtonType`, `javafx.scene.control.Dialog`, and `javafx.scene.control.DialogPane`.

I have done quite a bit of research and tried the following with no success:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled e(fx)clipse
- Manually added the jfxrt.jar file to the project
- Cleaned, rebuilt, and refreshed the project several times
- Removed the JRE from the build path and re-added it
- Recreated the project using New>JavaFX Project and copying the code
  over

Nothing seems to be working and I do not understand how just some classes in the package could be missing on one computer. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay well I figured this out about 5 minutes after posting the question... of course.

I looked through my installed Java builds under Program and Features on both computers. They looked the same, but I realized that my laptop is on Java 8u40, while my PC is on Java 8u25. I looked at the JavaDocs for javafx.scene.control.Dialog and, sure enough, it is labelled as `@since JavaFX 8u40` so I am installing the new JDK now.

Comment: lol - It took me a long time to find this and have the realization that that class is part of the jdk.

Answer (score -1):

You need:

```
javafx-dialogs-x.x.x.jar
```

and

```
javafx-ui-controls.jar
```

Described here:
[enter link description here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-dialogs/)