# Error resolving all javafx imports

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, importerror

I have a problem importing an existing project.

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

The error: The import javafx cannot be resolved.

I use Java 8 OpenJDK amd64 as the JRE System Library. Also i have no idea which version of java the primary version had if you would refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525483/some-javafx-imports-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse) solution. I use the newest version i can.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenJDK does not contain JavaFX. You need to install it separetely, if you want to stick with it. Please check out the OpenJFX project, that provides the open source version.

Or you might consider using Oracle's JDK, that contains it out of the box.

Comment: So which JRE would you recomment in this case?

Comment: You choice the JRE that fits your needs the best. So, if you want to have "less" efforts in using javafx, you might prefer an Oracle one over OpenJDK. If you prefer OpenJDK, you will have to install the required libraries yourself.